# How Do I Specify Locale of href in Like Box?

Tags: layout, localization, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

See my code below, my problem is that if I go directly to the link (using SO as example), I will get the Facebook layout in French which is what I want, but if I go via the Like Box link, Facebook strips the locale and the destination displays in my browser's default language of English.  How do I accomplish the destination in French without duplicating my Facebook page?
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609?ref=ts&locale=fr_CA

```
<html><body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-lang='fr_CA' data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609?ref=ts&locale=fr_CA" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>

</body></html>
```